# Creating parameterised prepared statements with Slick

Tags: scala, slick

In the following code:

```
val users = TableQuery[Users]
def getUserById(id:Int) = db(users.filter(_.id === id).result)
```

From what I understand, *getUserById* would create a prepared statement ***everytime*** the getUserById is executed and then discarded. Is there a way to cache the prepared statement so it is created only once and called many times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [documentation for Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/2.0.0-M3/connection.html#connection-pools) indicates that you need to enable prepared statement caching on the connection pool configuration.

Here is [quite a good article](http://fernandezpablo85.github.io/2013/04/07/slick_connection_pooling.html) on it also.

The summary is that Slick seems to cache the strings that are used to prepare the actual statements, but delegates the caching of the actual prepared statements to the underlying connection pool implementation.